# Using samba password to encrypt partition

Tags: samba, password, encryption

I have a local server with encrypted partition just for data, which I want to serve through samba server. I want to avoid re-entering password on each server start (e.g. on electricity failure) for partition encryption. Is it possible to use entered samba password as a passphrase for encrypted partition directly after connecting to samba server?

Comment: You can do this, but it were a much worse solution as your current version.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I don't think this is possible. I may be wrong. Depending on your host OS, you can have your OS look at a crypt-tab file. Here's a good guide for CentOS: [Crypto Disk in CentOS](http://www.gno.org/~gdr/sysadmin/centos/5/crypto-disk/server.html)

There's a really cool section in that guide which uses a USB key to boot. Almost like a TPM. ;)

Good luck!